# SQL Server : NVARCHAR column to store date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query that needs to be output in CSV.

No problem I say, but then this happens:

There are two columns (from and to date) which are date type, but I am trying to store them as `nvarchar` or `varchar` (tried both). This is in order to be able to insert the column headers in the extract.

I have tried a couple of `CONVERT`, `CAST`, `STUFF` to force the date in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD`, but to no avail.

Currently it is in this format: `Jan  1 2014 12:00AM`

I have tried almost everything I've found on Stack Overflow in similar topics, but nothing has worked for me.

I would also be happy if there could be an alternative on the column names, as I have not experimented with that one a lot.

Currently this is being used:

```
SELECT 'Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM [Database].[dbo].Table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `convert(varchar(10), col, 120)` which will truncate a date format of `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)` to `yyyy-mm-dd`

see [cast and convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx) for more details

```
SELECT 
     'id'          AS id
     , 'date_from' AS date_from
     , 'date_to'   AS date_to
UNION ALL
SELECT 
     convert(varchar(10), id)
     , convert(varchar(10), date_from, 120)
     , convert(varchar(10), date_to, 120) 
FROM [Database].[dbo].Table
```

Comment: Had to alter the column to ````date```` type. Afterwards this worked, thanks.